# Using hibernate tools to reverse engineer pojos from Postgres

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-tools

I am trying to reverse engineer pojos (using hibernate tools plugin v3.2.4x in eclipse 3.4.2) from a database that I have created in Postgres but my tables are being ignored. It works if I specify 'public' as the value for the 'hibernate.default_schema' property in my hibernate.cfg.xml file but if I try to specify a different schema then nothing is generated.

I've tried modifying the case (i.e. lower, upper, camel) but I still get the same result. Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="MyFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">[mypassword]</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testgis</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">locatimus</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is a picture of my setup in pgAdmin III - http://twitpic.com/snj8i

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing (or missing) something easy. As I say, if I change the schema to public then pojos from all tables in that schema are generated!

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. It seems that the table names must be in lowercase or hibernate tools does not see them. I don't know if this is a bug with the PostgresSQL dialect or Hibernate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Does the postgres user have permission to the tables in the locatimus schema ?

Comment: Yes, the postgres user has exactly the same permissions on both schemas (usage, create)