# I can not generate Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs from Database PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

have created my tables and relationships in the database PostgreSQL, but when I want to generate Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs, they are not generated

I applied all the appropriate steps to `hibernate.cfg.xml` generation and `hibernate.reveng.xml`

I think it's because the name tables and fields that I have in all uppercase, because I tested with another BD with the names of the tables in lower case and if it works normally, I show the script of my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."T_LNEA"(
 "ID_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "ID_CTGRIA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_LNEA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_LNEA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_LNEA")
;

CREATE TABLE "public"."T_SUB_LNEA"(
 "ID_SUB_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "ID_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

-- Add keys for table public.T_SUB_LNEA

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_SUB_LNEA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_SUB_LNEA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_SUB_LNEA")
;

CREATE TABLE "public"."T_CTGRIA"(
 "ID_CTGRIA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_CTGRIA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_CRITERIA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CTGRIA")
;
```

And an image that is loading the tables using the JBOS Tools.

[image]

But still I need support because I can not generate the POJOs.

Comment: Which tool you have used JPA or Hibernate for generating POJO's

Comment: Plugin Hibernate (JBOS Tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solve it somehow does not recognize the table name in uppercase, but if you recognize the attributes of the table in uppercase, so rename the tables in lowercase temporarily after he change in the EJB annotations, at least it works somehow.

Answer (score 4):

In the File "hibernate.reveng.xml" has the following

```
  <schema-selection match-catalog="mybd" match-schema="mybd"/>
```

You have to delete the **match-schema="mybd"**.

By default, when you use postgresql in hibernate, appears the match- schema , which does not happen in mysql , delete it and work , checked in Netbeans8.0

Comment: this should be the selected answer, (Sql Server). +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, as said before, if I change the name of the table and its fields in lowercase, if generates POJOs, the question is why is not generated in capital letters .....**

Comment: MySQL has a problem with capital letters, it always causes errors

Answer (score 0):

Une the reverse engineering tools provided by Hibernate. It depends on your IDE.
For example with NetBeans this is how it is done: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

Comment: Hello friend, I have also tried Netbeans with the same steps, but not generated, and does not indicate an error me ...

Comment: did you add the driver? And did you test the connection to the database? It works just fine, I use that all the time in all my projects, so you are missing something... I see in the pucture that you are using eclipse I guess, here is how to do http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/ this the official tutorial

Comment: Hi, as said before, if I change the name of the table and its fields in lowercase, if generates POJOs, the question is why is not generated in capital letters ...

Comment: this is a commun problem, so it's not really a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867699/using-hibernate-tools-to-reverse-engineer-pojos-from-postgres?rq=1

Comment: You solve it somehow does not recognize the table name in uppercase, but if you recognize the attributes of the table in uppercase, so rename the tables in lowercase temporarily after he change in the EJB annotations, at least it works somehow.