# Not generate Hibernate POJOs from Database PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have created my tables and relationships in the database PostgreSQL, but when I want to generate Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs, they are not generated

I applied all the appropriate steps to hibernate.cfg.xml generation and hibernate.reveng.xml

I think it's because the name tables and fields that I have in all uppercase, because I tested with another BD with the names of the tables in lower case and if it works normally, I show the script of my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."T_LNEA"(
 "ID_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "ID_CTGRIA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_LNEA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_LNEA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_LNEA")
;

CREATE TABLE "public"."T_SUB_LNEA"(
 "ID_SUB_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "ID_LNEA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

-- Add keys for table public.T_SUB_LNEA

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_SUB_LNEA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_SUB_LNEA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_SUB_LNEA")
;

CREATE TABLE "public"."T_CTGRIA"(
 "ID_CTGRIA" Integer NOT NULL,
 "DSCRPCION" Character varying(200)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

ALTER TABLE "public"."T_CTGRIA" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_ID_CRITERIA" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CTGRIA")
;
```

And an image that is loading the tables using the JBOS Tools.

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140725043241974386.png

But still I need support because I can not generate the POJOs.
I've also tried with netbeans and does not generate anything.

Comment: They'll not be generated automatically, you have to do that part.

Comment: Then friend no other way to generate such offal, perhaps with another tool ?

Comment: Perhaps write some code to generate code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can not generate Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs from Database PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360396/i-can-not-generate-hibernate-mapping-files-and-pojos-from-database-postgresql)